# Dropdown isn't showing selected option

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create a dropdown which allows my admin users to be able to select what course they would like a question added to, I have it so it changes the state of the courseUrl, However, when the user selects an option, it doesn't change the selected option on the dropdown itself, which doesn't give my user any feedback.

**Dropdown**

```
<select
  name="courseUrl"
  id="courseUrl"
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  value={this.state.course}
>
  {
    courses.length && courses.map(course => {
      return <option value={course.courseUrl} key={course.courseName}></option>
    })
  }
</select>
```

**handleChange**

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value })
}
```

Comment: Your `key` seems to be set incorrectly.

Comment: @usafder I thought that too, it worked before when everything was courseName instead of courseUrl, I've changed it to course.courseUrl and it still isn't working?

Comment: handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ course: e.target.value })
}

Comment: I have created a sample demo. check this - https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-antonelli-z3t9n?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the on change function, you should set it to only the value, not the filed id since the dropdown value is `value={this.state.course}`:

```
handleChange = (e) => { this.setState({ course: e.target.value }) }
```